# If not in collection then add to select list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, conditional-statements, selectlist

I am working with html helpers for dropdown boxes and I want to populate a select list if an object is NOT in another ICollection property in my Model.

Basically it's an app to do with teams and I want to be able to check if a player has been selected to start against a team and if he/she is in the starting team list then they wont be an option on the dropdown lists in the picksSubs view.

Apologies for the open endedness of this query. Please offer any suggestions you might have!

Many thanks,

J

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Selected { get; set; }

    public List<Person> All { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Exclude { get; set; }

    // Create selectlist of items which are not in exclude list
    public SelectList GetSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            var r = All.Where(q => !Exclude.Any(p => p.ID == q.ID)).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
            return new SelectList(r, "ID", "Name", Selected);
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        All = new List<Person>();
        Exclude = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

In view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Selected,Model.GetSelectList)
```